# Upload to AzureFile Storage Not Blob

Tags: file, powershell, azure, storage, powershell-cmdlet

Though I'm not a powershell script master I'm having the strugle to upload some ziped files to my Azure File Storage.

I've tried the following script which I've scrambled through 
microsofts guides ( " https://learn.microsoft.com/sv-se/powershell/module/azure.storage/set-azurestoragefilecontent?view=azurermps-1.2.9 ")

```
$StorageAccountName = "MyAccountName"
$StorageAccountKey = "TheKeyThat I have"
$ctx = New-AzureStorageContext -StorageAccountName $StorageAccountName `
         -StorageAccountKey $StorageAccountKey
         Set-AzureStorageFileContent archive archive\Test\ C:\Users\User\Desktop\MoveFrom\*.* -Context $context'
```

The problem which I have is i'm getting this error

```
Set-AzureStorageFileContent : The specified source file 'archive\Test\' was not found.
At line:5 char:10
+          Set-AzureStorageFileContent archive archive\Test\ C:\Users\User\De ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Set-AzureStorageFileContent], FileNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FileNotFoundException,Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Storage.File.Cmdlet.SetAzureStorageFileContent
```

The share is named archive and inside the archive we have different folders one folder that is named Test. So I dont get it why it's complaining about the source file missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I don't think you can upload a folder using `Set-AzureStorageFileContent`. You would need to upload individual files.

Also, there's an issue with the usage of this Cmdlet. Please refer to the documentation [`here`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azure.storage/set-azurestoragefilecontent). Based on the documentation, please try the following:

```
$source = "<path to source file>"
Set-AzureStorageFileContent -ShareName "archive" -Source $source -Path "Test" -Context $ctx
```

If you wish to upload a folder in `Azure File Share`, may I suggest you take a look at [`AzCopy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-use-azcopy#file-upload). To upload all files from a folder, you would use AzCopy like this:

```
AzCopy /Source:C:\myfolder /Dest:https://myaccount.file.core.windows.net/myfileshare/ /DestKey:key /S
```

Comment: This worked without problems but then I have assigned just one ziped file to be uploaded. Wont it work to use " $source = "C:\Users\User\Desktop\MoveFrom\*.*" " ? too upload all the files that are in the source folder?

Comment: No it won't as this Cmdlet will only upload a single file. You can use AzCopy as I mentioned if you want to upload a folder.

Comment: Well I tried the AzCopy, installed it from the page that was linked. Restarted POwershell and had this comandline (" AzCopy /C:\Users\User\Desktop\MoveFrom /Dest:https://StorageName.file.core.windows.net/archive/Test /DestKey:MyKey /S ") but get the following error "The term 'AzCopy' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, sc" - I'm not able to use the Powershell with AzCopy?

Comment: Try to run AzCopy from the directory where it is installed. You would need to open command prompt.

Comment: Managed to get it to work with azcopy. But is there a way to automate this with "Time Schedule"?

Comment: I would suggest asking a different question for this.